# os.system() inline expression is not changing my PATH

Tags: python, mingw, windows-8.1, os.system

I'm using **Python 2.7.6** and **Windows 8.1** and I'm attempting to change my path in a subprocess with `os.sytem()` to  use some UNIX commands in that line (with MinGW/MSYS environment):

**input**

```
>>> os.system(r'set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin && set PATH && ls')
```

**output**

```
Path=ALL_MY_OLD_PATHS;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
"ls" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
1
```

I mean with *ALL_MY_OLD_PATHS* to all the dirs that I've in my system, and as you can see **C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin** is correctly added to my path, but when it's executed "ls" command isn't known.

What am I doing wrong? Could it be caused by the time delay which is too small to refresh the PATH with this new one? How could I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you haven't misspelled the directory where `ls` is located, i.e. that `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` is exactly the right location?

An easier way to modify the path might be with `os.putenv`:

```
os.putenv("PATH", r'%s;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin' % os.getenv("PATH"))
```

Then you can use `os.system` in the normal way, with simply `os.system("ls")` and such.

You might also want to consider switching to the more powerful [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for invocation of external commands.